# new commands are installed but they still don't work

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm-install, create-react-app, npm-live-server

Friends-MacBook-Pro:~ friend$ npm install -g live-server

/Users/friend/.npm-global/bin/live-server -> /Users/friend/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/live-server/live-server.js

- live-server@1.2.0
  updated 1 package in 15.078s
  Friends-MacBook-Pro:~ friend$ live-server -v

-bash: live-server: command not found

Friends-MacBook-Pro:~ friend$ npm install -g create-react-app
/Users/friend/.npm-global/bin/create-react-app -> /Users/friend/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
+ create-react-app@1.4.3
added 106 packages in 13.884s

╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                     │
   │   Update available 5.5.1 → 5.6.0    │
   │     Run npm i -g npm to update      │
   │                                     │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────╯

Friends-MacBook-Pro:~ friend$ npm i -g npm
+ npm@1.0.0

added 1 package in 1.566s

Friends-MacBook-Pro:~ friend$ create-react-app newtypelabs.io

-bash: create-react-app: command not found

Comment: What exactly is your question? What specifically is not working? Your question is not clear. Please take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the bin path to your user environment.

```
echo 'export PATH="/Users/friend/.npm-global/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```